# Bandgap Spacing in Photonic Crystals

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, optics, visible-light, crystals

I am doing some self-study on photonics and have encountered the following question:

> *We know that amorphous electronic crystals such as [amorphous silicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_silicon) have a bandgap. Can amorphous photonic crystals also have a bandgap? Roughly how large would the spacing, d, have to be for a bandgap centered around ~ 600 nm?*

Here is my solution:
Since $n\lambda=2dsin(\theta)$, if $\lambda=600 nm, \theta=\pi/4, n=1,$ then $d=4.24 \times 10^{-7}$.

Could somebody check over my work?

Comment: What exactly is an amorphous photonic crystal? One which has no long-range order?

Comment: Also, isn't the Bragg formula used for constructive interference? If so you'd have to take d*0.5